# Function Arguments - Clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Q - Write a function consonant(ch) that returns whether or not the string ch is a consonant letter. You can assume ch is a string containing only alphabetical characters.

My code:

```
l = ['a','e','i','o','u']

def consonant(ch):

    if ch in l:
        return False
    else:
        return True

x = consonant(g) # Doesn't work NameError g is not defined 
print(x)
```

It gives a NameError: name 'g' is not defined.

However if I give the argument as a string(character), it works:

```
x = consonant('g')  # Works
```

I can not understand why is it not transferring the value g to ch in the first case like it is in the second case.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with function arguments. If you had done `if g in ['a','e','i','o','u']: print("vowel")`, then you'd get a NameError all the same, no function required.

Comment: `consonant(g)` is passing the variable named `g` not the string `g` like in the second `consonant('g')`. And since you have no variable named `g` it gives you a NameError.

Comment: Can you clarify your confusion? ``g`` (without quotes) is not a value, it is a name. Unless you define which value that name refers to, it has no meaning (thus triggering the ``NameError``). What value did you expect ``g`` to have?

Comment: If `print(x)` outputs the variable `x`, then what does `consonant(g)` do…?

Answer (score 3):

`g` is a variable with the name `g`. Just like `x` is in `x = consonant('g')`.

`'g'` is the literal string `'g'`.

Be aware that your code does not support upper case characters.

Unrelated but

```
if ch in l:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Can be simplified to

```
return ch not in l
```